# How to apply default tkinter font to all the tkinter windows

Tags: python, tkinter

In the following code "font" (defined in the config file) applies only to the Tkinter window that was initiated first, in this case, "gui". If I switch the order, it applied to the "calibration" window, but not to the "gui" window. How can I extend it to both "gui" and "calibration" windows?

```
gui = tk.Tk()
calibration = tk.Tk()

defaultFont = tkFont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
defaultFont.configure(family=font, size=9)
```

Comment: I don't think `tkinter` windows have fonts attached to them. The fonts are attached to the thing that is holding the text like a `tk.Text` or `tk.Label` or `tk.Button` ... Basically every time you create a widget that can accept a font, use `font=defaultFont`

Comment: I am able to manipulate the whole gui window font with the default font method so I think it exists. I changed the font size to 1 to make sure, and every text in gui window indeed changed to almost nothing.

Comment: Your code won't run as written. You haven't defined `font`.

Comment: @TheLizzard: that is not correct. Fonts are objects which can be shared by one or more widgets.  While it's true you can associate a specific font with a specific widget, using font objects is almost always the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two instances of `Tk` are completely isolated from each other. A single font configuration cannot apply to both at the same time.

Generally speaking, you should never create two instances of `Tk`. If you need more than one window, the second and subsequate windows should be instances of `Tk`. When you do that, this problem goes away.

However, if you need to create two instances of `Tk` then you need to configure the font for each one separately. Unfortunately, `nametofont` assumes only a single root window so it can't be used. However, the body of that function is a single line of code, so we can just replicate that to supply the extra option for specifying which root window to configure.

Here is how to get and configure the default font in multiple windows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

gui = tk.Tk()
calibration = tk.Tk()

for window in (gui, calibration):
    defaultFont = tkFont.Font(root=window, name="TkDefaultFont", exists=True)
    defaultFont.configure(family=font, size=9)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I suspected that creating 2 instances of Tk is not the way. I will use your solution for now, and try to move calibration window under gui instance.